# is function continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let G be the real line with addition as the group operation and with the topology for which the open sets are those that either are empty or have a countable complement  then we want to show that (x,y) $\mapsto$ x+y is continuous if either one of the entries is held fixed. This is my approach. Suppose that $x_0$ $\in$ $G$ is fixed. Let $U$ be open in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $U$:=$\mathbb{R}$-$\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for some countable collection $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$. The complete preimage of $U$ is
\begin{eqnarray}
\nonumber \{(x_0,y) \in \{x_0\} \times \mathbb{R}: x_0+y \in U \} &=& \{(x_0, y) \in \{ x_0 \} \times \mathbb{R} : x_0+y \neq x_n, n \in N \}\\
\nonumber &=&\{(x_0,y) \in \{ x_0 \} \times \mathbb{R}:y \neq x_n-x_0,  n \in N \}\\
\nonumber &=&\{x_0\} \times (\mathbb{R}-\{x_n-x_0\}_{n=1}^{\infty}).
\end{eqnarray}

How to show that this set is open $\in \{x_0\} \times \mathbb{R}$ to show that the map [($x_0$,$y$) $\longmapsto$ $x_0$+$y$]: $\{$ $x_0$ $\}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\longrightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Comment: Can you express it as $(U\times V)\cap (\{x_0\}\times \mathbb{R})$ for some open sets $U,V\subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, i cann't. If we take $V= \mathbb{R} -\{x_n-x_0\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and it is open in the countable complement topology but how can i take $V$ to be open also in this topology and such that $(U \times V) \cap (\{x_0\} \times \mathbb{R})$ = the preimage of U.

Comment: @Roba: The set $U$ in Prahlad Vaidyanathan's comment is not the same $U$ as in your question. All that's needed is to find an open set containing $x_{0}$.

Comment: But U which is in my question containing $x_0$, why don't we take it?

Comment: Note that $m_{x_0}:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R, y\mapsto x_0+y$ is a bijection $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Bijections are invertible and their inverses preserve cardinality. So $m_{x_0}^{-1}(k)$ is countable whenever $k$ is a countable set. This means that the preimage of any closed set is closed, and $m_{x_0}$ is continous.